# Google Script to open URL in same window as Spreadsheet

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work around the lack of API for Google Spreahsheet's Filter Views, by passing the filter view's URL into a hyperlink displayed in a sidebar.

Importantly: I want the filter view URL to open **in the same window** as, and thus replace, the spreadsheet. The hyperlink target should then be `_self`

```
function listFilterViews(){
  var uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
      .setTitle('Teacher Views');
  var panel = uiInstance.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setSpacing(5)
  var scroll = uiInstance.createScrollPanel();
  scroll.setHeight("100%")
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/blablabla"
  var link = uiInstance.createAnchor("click me", url)
  link.setTarget("_self")
  panel.add(link);
  scroll.add(panel)
  uiInstance.add(scroll);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(uiInstance);
}
```

However, the URL doesn't open in the same window as expected but in an other window instead. How can I fix this?

Comment: From the documentation:   By design, these hyperlinks always open in a new page. Links that reload the current page are not allowed.

Comment: Sad. But that's worth an answer I belive, @Sergeinsas

Comment: I'd rather leave it as a comment since I'm not sure it's "really" impossible... maybe someone found some way to work around... I don't know ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [setTarget documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor#setTarget(String)):

"(setting a target to _self) will only work if the app is being shown as a standalone service. It will have no effect when called inside a dialog, such as in a Google Spreadsheet."

Apps Script intentionally prevents scripts from being able to switch the view of the current window, as a security measure.